# Shared preferences between Unity, Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I need to pass some key-value pairs between Unity and Android. I know I can do this with plugin, like this: [Using shared preferences between unity and native android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682977/using-shared-preferences-between-unity-and-native-android-sdk)

Surprisingly, my colleague (who's doing the same thing on iOS) told me that she can use `NSUserDefaults` and `PlayerPrefs` to do this easily.

So I try to write key-value on Unity side:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Location","tw");
```

and read on Android side using `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Location = sharedPref.getString("Location", null);
```

but I got nothing, am I doing it wrong?

Or is there another tool to use on Android which have the same effect as `NSUserDefaults` and `PlayerPrefs` mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nailed it

According to http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/what-is-default-shared-preference-name.66579/

should use

```
SharedPreferences packagePrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of Unity you might need to add `.v2.playerprefs` to the Android package name.

So:

```
SharedPreferences unityPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + ".v2.playerprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Any idea which version of Unity does need this since?