# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'on a null object reference

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, plugins, native

I'm not used to working with java, but I need to modify a unity plugin to save a value to sharedPreferences. So following this answer

[Using shared preferences between unity and native android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682977/using-shared-preferences-between-unity-and-native-android-sdk)

I created two methods in a (pre-existing) class of the plugin in question, and a variable:

```
public static final String MY_CURRENT_PATH = "CurrentPhotoPath";
```

//set value

public void setPreferenceString (String prefKey, String prefValue) {
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(this.MY_CURRENT_PATH, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(prefKey, prefValue);
editor.commit();

```
}


//Get value
public String getPreferenceString (String prefKey) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(this.MY_CURRENT_PATH, 0);
        String playerName = settings.getString(prefKey, "");
        return playerName;
}
```

Observing the errors on android studio's LogCat I can see that my application crashes when I try to call getPreferenceString (the Get value method) from a method in unity similar to this

public static string GetPreferenceString(string prefKey)
{
AndroidJavaObject AJO = null;

```
    if (AJO == null)
        AJO = new AndroidJavaObject("com.aaa.unity.classname", new object[0]);

    if (AJO == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return AJO.Call<string>("getPreferenceString", new object[] { prefKey });
}
```

so the result error log is "AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Share
dPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
at com.aaa.unity.classname.getPreferenceString(NativeGalleryMediaPickerResultOperation.java:65)

-where raw 65 is SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(this.MY_CURRENT_PATH, 0);

(The the set-value method, which I call earlier of the problematic one, doesn't seem to give any errors, but it's not clear to me where it saves the sharedpreferences)

So my question is: what about the attempt turns out to be null?
Did I miss some step in creating the sharedpreferences on java side?
I may have to initialize them somehow before I can use them?
maybe I didn't create the external file that contains them?
And if so, how do I create it?

Comment: Do you have context ? I think you are not passing or fetching context that's why your game is crashing.

Comment: yes, the class has a context and initializes it in this function

Comment: public NativeGalleryMediaPickerResultOperation( final Context context, final NativeGalleryMediaReceiver mediaReceiver, final Intent data, final boolean selectMultiple, final String savePathDirectory, final String savePathFilename )
 {
  this.context = context;
  this.mediaReceiver = mediaReceiver;
  this.data = data;
  this.selectMultiple = selectMultiple;
  this.savePathDirectory = savePathDirectory;
  this.savePathFilename = savePathFilename;

 }

Comment: do i need to initialize it in my functions as well?

Comment: Yes, try to provide context

Comment: i can't init it on functions, it is create  only in the constructor of the class

Comment: NativeGalleryMediaPickerResultOperation resultOperation = new NativeGalleryMediaPickerResultOperation( getActivity(), mediaReceiver, data, selectMultiple, savePathDirectory, savePathFilename );

Comment: public String getPreferenceString (Context myContext, String prefKey) {
        SharedPreferences settings = myContext.getSharedPreferences(this.MY_CURRENT_PATH, 0);
        String playerName = settings.getString(prefKey, "");
        return playerName;
}
Use like this and provide context from Unity

Comment: it was it. it was the context. no more errors now. thank you jaimin